# jQuery running C# code after other codes

Tags: c#, jquery

I have a click event on a button which runs some code which is in C# so I put my C# code in jQuery using `@{...}` however, codes in `@{...}` runs after other codes.

HTML Code:

```
   <button type="submit" id="TestRegex" class="btn btn-default">Test Regex</button>
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#TestRegex").click(function () {
            @{
                var testdata = Request["TestData"];
                var expression = Request["RegexPattern"];
                string regexMatchResult = "No Match";
                string dateMatchResult = "No Match";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(testdata) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression))
                {
                    bool regexMatch =
                        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(testdata, expression, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    bool dateMatch = false;

                    foreach (var item in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(testdata, expression))
                    {
                        dateMatch = string.Compare(item.ToString(), testdata, true) == 0;
                    }

                    regexMatchResult = regexMatch ? "RegEx Match" : "No Match";
                    dateMatchResult = dateMatch ? "Date Matches" : "No Match";
                }
              }

            $('#RegExMatch').text("@regexMatchResult");    //
            $('#DateMatchResult').text("@dateMatchResult"); // These codes are run before codes above

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this part should be at the top

```
@{
                var testdata = Request["TestData"];
                var expression = Request["RegexPattern"];
                string regexMatchResult = "No Match";
                string dateMatchResult = "No Match";

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(testdata) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(expression))
                {
                    bool regexMatch =
                        System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(testdata, expression, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                    bool dateMatch = false;

                    foreach (var item in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(testdata, expression))
                    {
                        dateMatch = string.Compare(item.ToString(), testdata, true) == 0;
                    }

                    regexMatchResult = regexMatch ? "RegEx Match" : "No Match";
                    dateMatchResult = dateMatch ? "Date Matches" : "No Match";
                }
              }
```

and then in Script tag

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#RegExMatch').text("@regexMatchResult");    //
     $('#DateMatchResult').text("@dateMatchResult");


     $("#TestData").text("@testdata "); 
     $("#RegexPattern").text("@expression "); 
 });
```

Comment: That worked perfectly... Is there any way of no clearing the value in my textbox (TestData and RegexPattern)?

Comment: did you mean to persist the values in these textboxes after click event executed?

Comment: Yes...That's exactly what i mean

Comment: Thats how my label and textbox looks:
            `@Html.Label("RegEx Pattern", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <input type="text" name="RegexPattern" class="form-control" />
             
            @Html.Label("TestData", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    
                <input type="text" name="TestData" class="form-control" />`
       `

Comment: I think it might help you.

Comment: I've changed it however the value is not reappearing... While debugging, value in `@testdata` and `@expression` is correct however, it looks like texbox ID is not matching

Comment: simply add "Id" attribute to your input with same value as in "name" attribute and try the updated code

Comment: If your values got cleared, then how did you came to know it worked. What I understood from above code is that you want to validate some textbox with regex and you run some javascript code before finally executing some bunch of functions in document ready. The point I don't understand is that where is the dynamism for calling regex function on button click.

Comment: I've tried that however, it's still not persisting the value

Comment: I'm using a tool called firebug to debug the jquery and I can see the value in `@testdata` however, it's not putting the value back in the textbox